# OpenGL/GLUT surface normals of cone

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I created a cone with `GL_TRIANGLE_FAN`

```
// draw the upper part of the cone
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
glVertex3f(0, 0, height);
for (int angle = 0; angle < 360; angle++) {
    glVertex3f(sin(angle) * radius, cos(angle) * radius, 0);
}
glEnd();

// draw the base of the cone
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
glVertex3f(0, 0, 0);
for (int angle = 0; angle < 360; angle++) {
    // normal is just pointing down
    glNormal3f(0, -1, 0);
    glVertex3f(sin(angle) * radius, cos(angle) * radius, 0);
}
glEnd();
```

How do I get the surface normals? For the bottom am I right to say normal is just pointing down?

**UPDATE**

I tried using

```
for (int angle = 0; angle < 360; angle++) {
    glNormal3f(sin(angle), cos(angle), 0);
    glVertex3f(sin(angle) * radius, cos(angle) * radius, 0);
}
```

But it looks weird in some angles ...

[image]

[image]

2nd image looks like just 1 solid color?

Comment: this question might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12128129/smooth-cone-normals

Comment: Your mantle normal needs `(sin, 0, cos)` as the "upwards" part (Y coordinate) does not change. However, the Y coordinate (and the other two too) depend on the angle of the cones slope, so it is more like `(cos(slopeAngle) * sin(angle), sin(slopeAngle), cos(slopeAngle) * cos(angle))`.

Comment: @Nobody, wheres the mantle?

Comment: @JiewMeng: Hmm, this was a translation error. I only know the german term (Mantelfläche). I meant the face of the cone which is not the bottom. The right word might be lateral surface.

Comment: As a side note: Don't forget to set the correct normal for the tip of the cone. As it is contributing in all triangles it should point straight up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming your cone has height `h` and radius `r` and its as standing (say its tip points into +Y direction) the lateral face normal depends on two angles: the angle of the circular ground area and the angle of the cone's tip (lets call it cone angle or α). This cone angle in turn depends on the ratio of `h` and `r`.

Looking at the crossection of the cone we see basically a right angle triangle, whose one cathedus has length `h` and the other one `r`. Lets assume that the `h` cathetus goes straight up the Y axis from the origin and the `r` cathetus one does the same along the X axis. Now we want to calculate the normal of the hypothenuse point outwards.

[image: Angle proof and normal coordinates]

Doing some angle math on the triangle we can see that the normal of the hyponetuse has following form:

```
(cos(coneAngle), sin(coneAngle))
```

with

```
coneAngle = atan(r / h)
```

This is of course only in 2D and we need the 3D equivalent.
At first we need the normal of a circle in the XZ plane.
This can be written as

```
(cos(circleAngle), 0, sin(circleAngle))
```

And now we can combine these two to one normal equation. Our slope normal has a horizontal and a vertical part. The vertical part goes directly into the Y coordinate, while the horizontal part contributes to both horizontal direction (X and Z):

```
(cos(coneAngle) * cos(circleAngle), sin(coneAngle), cos(coneAngle) * sin(circleAngle))
```

Basically there are two vectors: The up vector which points to the tip of the cone and the horizontal vector, which is the one generated by the circle normal. These two vectors form a base and what I have done here is to apply a linear transformation from the XY 2D space (of the cone normal) into the space spanned by the circle normal and the up vector (Y axis). To do this transformation you multiply the components of the XY space vector with the respective base vectors of the other space and sum the result together, so you basically calculate:

```
cos(coneAngle) * (cos(circleAngle), 0, sin(circleAngle)) + sin(coneAngle) * (0, 1, 0)
```

### Update

I just noticed that the two triangles in the hypothenuse normal image are similar, which means, that one can calculate the normal without trigonometric functions:
Given the length of the hypothenuse `c = sqrt(h * h + r * r)` we know from the similarity of the triangles that:

```
n_x / 1 = n_x = h / c
```

and

```
n_y / 1 = n_y = r / c
```

Therefore, the hypothenuse normal is:

```
1/c * (h, r)
```

Incidentally, multiplying by the factor `1/c` is a mere normalization of the vector `(h, r)`.

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed explaination. There are 2 things I don't understand completely. By circle angle, I believe its the `angle` variable in code? Also, in the last step, combining the normals, why is it multiply (not that I know of another method, just want to understand why its used)?

Comment: Yes `circleAngle` is like your `angle`. As to the second: I have updated my answer to give an explanation (as it would not fit into the comment).

Comment: Sorry, I am not really understanding why "*the horizontal part contributes to both horizontal direction (X and Z)*" which I believe contributes to the last term `cos(coneAngle) * sin(circleAngle)`. The way I see it, that vector only has XY values? How did the contribution of Z axis come about?

Comment: As I already explained the 2 coordinates of the 2D cone normal (or better hypothenuse normal) are factors to each of the base's vectors. These two vectors are the circle normal `(cos(circleAngle), 0, sin(circleAngle))` and the up vector `(0, 1, 0)`. Multiplying a vector by a factor multiplies all components with this factor. Maybe this [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinate_vector) will help you.

Comment: The normals work but it seems they follow the surface. I have a sphere (code mostly from lecturer) and it has its highlight on left no matter how I rotate it. But for the cone with smooth shading like we discussed, it follows the surface of the cone. See http://screenr.com/yTqH

Comment: Maybe you should open up another question where you can compare the code for the flat and smooth shading?

Comment: @Jiew Meng looks like you forgetting to transform your normals