# Getting normal point on a Cone

Tags: graphics

I'm trying to get cone primitives working in my ray tracer. I got intersections of a cone and ray working. However, I do not know how to get the normals of the cone from the way the cone is defined.
I define my cone with the following:

```
pos -- The vertex  of the cone
size -- Height of the cone
direction -- A unit vector that defines the direction of the cone
angle --  The angle of the cone
```

(For more info I followed how [Intersection of line and Cone](http://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/IntersectionLineCone.pdf) as a reference on how it is defined).

From what I gather I can use [two tangents of a point with the parametric eqn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12128320/3024116), and using their cross product get the normal. However I don't know how to get the parametric eqn given the way I defined my cone, and two tangents to the parametric eqn.

If somehow has another method to get the find the normals that would be great to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up applying the grad function to the cone equation `(x*a+y*b+z*c)^2-(a^2+b^2+c^2)(x^2+y^2+z^2)cos(t)^2` where

1. {x,y,z} = 3d point (point of normal in question)
2. {a,b,c} = direction vector
3. t = angle of cone

Then using [wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=grad%28%28x*a%2By*b%2Bz*c%29%5E2-%28a%5E2%2Bb%5E2%2Bc%5E2%29%28x%5E2%2By%5E2%2Bz%5E2%29cos%28t%29%5E2%29), this ends up giving me

- x = (2 a (a x+b y+c z)-2 (a^2+b^2+c^2) x cos^2(t))
- y = (2 b (a x+b y+c z)-2 (a^2+b^2+c^2) y cos^2(t))
- z = (2 c (a x+b y+c z)-2 (a^2+b^2+c^2) z cos^2(t))

and `normal={x,y,z}`